# How to read this kanji? (see image)

Tags: meaning, kanji

All the methods I know failed. My count is 7 strokes, but may be wrong. I think the key is the bottom part, but no radical matches its shape.

[image: hard to identify kanji]

The rest of the word, including particle, is: きながらでも

The full sentence is: パンなんか [?]きながらでも 食{た}べられるでしょー！

I tried to stroke the kanji here http://kanji.sljfaq.org/draw.html with no success.

Comment: You want to read it or you want to know its stroke count? The top element is four strokes and means "stop". The bottom element is four strokes and means "few". As you learn more characters you lot to spot common elements, which helps you know what's one long stroke and what's two short strokes, which helps you work out the stroke count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's 歩, as in 歩{ある}く, and the radical is 止. It has **8 strokes**, and is formed by combining 止 and 少.

Stroke order and other miscellaneous information can be found [here](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%AD%A9).

[image: stroke order]

Comment: I understand now. I was drawing the vertical line as a single stroke.

Comment: Ahh yeah, that can be confusing. Just try to think of it as 止 + 少 and not as its own thing.

Comment: @HatoruHansou If you're not sure about the stroke count, on jisho.org you can also use the kanji's parts/radicals to look it up

Comment: @waldrumpus I know to search by radicals too. But for this one I was decoding it incorrectly. Now that I see it correctly separated in radicals I don't know why I looked at 止 and not recognized it as part of this character. If drawn in the correct order is easy to get it at kanji.sljfaq.org too.